# Consistent Augmented Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Well, the linear system which at least has one solution is called "**consistent**" linear system.
Find an equation involving g, h, and k that makes
this augmented matrix correspond to a consistent system:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 &-4  &7  &g \\ 
0 & 3 & -5 &h \\ 
-2 & 5 & -9 &k 
\end{bmatrix}$$

Alright, we perform some steps:
 1- We add 1 times row two to row three.
2- We multiply row one by 2.
3- We sum the row one and three.
But when we do step three, we get $2g+h+k=0$.It means that this equation should hold for the system to be consistent - I think my problem is just at the aforementioned step - However, I think when we get things like $0=0$ or $2=2$ , and these kind of equations which are **true** then we have infinite solutions.Am I right?
I have tested my answer and it doesn't work!
The real answer is $k-2g+h=0$, but **why**?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're right ! the textbook answer is incorrect. You may figure that out easily by plugging in $g=1,~h=1~k=1$  - if you try to solve the system with these values you would see that its inconsistent.

Comment: @ganeshie8 I'm not right, if you put $g=1$, $h=1$, $k=1$ according to the answer of the textbook you get $0=0$, but according to my answer the equation won't be satisfied, $2+1+1=0$ which is not true!

Comment: Are you really sure below give you $0=0$ as last row ? $$\begin{bmatrix}
1 &-4  &7  &1 \\ 
0 & 3 & -5 &1 \\ 
-2 & 5 & -9 &1 
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: @ganeshie8 No, I say that $2g+h+k=0$ - which is my answer - should hold for the linear system to be consistent, but it doesn't hold if you substitute $h=1$, $k=1$, $g=1$.So my answer is wrong, and I'm asking why it is wrong!!

Comment: Your answer is right.  $h=1,k=1,g=1$ satisfies the textbook answer but it gives you inconsistent system. So the textbook answer is wrong.

Comment: The given augmented matrix is consistent for all values of $g,h,k$ that satisfy your answer :  $$2g+h+k = 0$$

Comment: @ganeshie8 That's really weird, I'd plugged in stuff and my answer didn't work.Personal mistake :), thanks!

Comment: happens haha! you're welcome :)